# Modify image on div mouseover

Tags: css, reactjs, image, jsx

I have a basic Card.

[image]

I want the image to change its `src` when I mouseover on the **card**.
I can change the image when I mouseover on the `<img/>` tag itself like so :

```
<img src={item.iconUrl}
     onMouseOver={e => (e.currentTarget.src = item.iconHoverUrl)}
     onMouseOut={e => (e.currentTarget.src = item.iconHoverUrl)}
     className="mr-3 avatar-lg rounded" alt="app_icon" 
/>
```

But I don't find any way to reference this image's `src` when I'm out of it's scope.
I tried setting the content of `src` into a variable and changing it's value on the card's mouseover but that won't trigger an update of the `src` of the image so it doesn't work either.

Here is the code of the component if it helps :

```
<Card className="app-hover" style={{ marginTop: '10px', height: '92%', overflow: 'hidden' }}>
<CardBody className="p-3">
    <Media>
        <img src={item.iconUrl}
            onMouseOver={e => (e.currentTarget.src = item.iconHoverUrl)}
            onMouseOut={e => (e.currentTarget.src = item.iconHoverUrl)}
            className="mr-3 avatar-lg rounded" alt="app_icon" />
        <Media body>
            <Row style={{ marginLeft: '4px', marginTop: '15px' }}>
                <h5 className="mt-1 mb-0">{this.props.i18n.language === 'en' ? item.title : item.titleFR}</h5>
            </Row>
        </Media>
    </Media>
    <Row>
        <Col lg={6}>
            <Media>
                <CreditCard className="icon-dual align-self-center mr-2"></CreditCard>
                <Media body>
                    <h5 className="mt-2 pt-1  font-size-16">{this.props.i18n.language === 'en' ? 'Not Owned' : 'Non-Acquis'}</h5>
                </Media>
            </Media>
        </Col>
        <Col lg={6}>
            <Media>
                <Users className="icon-dual align-self-center mr-2"></Users>
                <Media body>
                    <h5 className="mt-2 pt-1 font-size-16">
                        {
                            item.stats ? item.stats.users : ''
                        }
                    </h5>
                </Media>
            </Media>
        </Col>

    </Row>

    <Row className="mt-2 border-top pt-2" style={{ paddingLeft: '8px', paddingRight: '8px' }}>
        <p className="text-muted">{this.props.i18n.language === 'en' ? item.shortDescription : item.shortDescriptionFR}</p>
    </Row>
</CardBody>
```

Is it possible to do it the way I have it setup? As you can obviously see from the code, the image is fetched from an api and always changing so I can't simply hardcode the animation in CSS.

Comment: I think `ref` in react can help you to get `<img> ` dom node reference.

Comment: This seems like it would a good time to make it stateful like `const [src, setSrc] = useState(item.iconUrl)` and then toggling that state variable on mouse events?

Comment: @TomFinney I thought I understood stateful components but since I'm new to React I can't wrap my head around what you just explained. Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not try to change the DOM "directly", instead you should call a function that mutate the state and use the new icon from the state itself. Let me explain with an example:

```
const [icon, setIcon] = useState("");

const onMouseOver = () => setIcon("the-over-icon");

const onMouseOut = () => setIcon("the-not-over-icon");

// ...
<Card onMouseOver={onMouseOver} onMouseOut={onMouseOut}>
    <img src={icon} />
</Card>
```

Comment: This seems like a good recommendation for the image itself but does it really answer my question? If so I don't understand how it relates to the Card parent.

Comment: Make sense now?

Answer (score 1):

I will extract img into functional component. In Typescript something like.

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

interface IMyImgProps{
    iconUrl: string;
    iconHoverUrl: string;
}

export const MyImg: React.FunctionComponent<IMyImgProps> = props => {
    const [icon, setIcon] = useState(props.iconUrl);

    const onMouseOver = () => setIcon(props.iconHoverUrl);
    const onMouseOut = () => setIcon(props.iconUrl);

    return <img src={icon} onMouseOver={onMouseOver} onMouseOut={onMouseOut} />
}
```

Comment: It's nice but it doesn't apply it to the Card as requested. But the answer above explained further how to apply it to the parent element. Thanks ! :)

Comment: Hi I have seen previous answer not clear before its update.  So you can use it like:

<Card>
    <MyImg iconUrl={icon1} iconHoverUrl={icon2}/>
</Card>

Its always better to decompose components into smaller once. You will get better experience, testing etc.